# Can I update a Salesforce Synchronized object with data that is stored in a Local Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

I have a synchronized Object from Salesforce, connected to Marketing Cloud through the MC Connector. However, some of those fields are empty, and I want to fill them through a Landing Page I created in Marketing Cloud.

I did an automation with an SQL Query so as to fill a Local Data Extension that merges the data coming from the Landing Page with the data on the Synchronized Object stored in Salesforce, filling a local Data Extension.

However, now I need to send that data back to Salesforce so as to populate that object. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. The Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud sync is one-way only. Contrary to Sales Cloud to Pardot, which provides a bi-directional integration.

There is however a number of methods to update Sales Cloud records from Marketing Cloud using connector:

1. Use AmpScript function [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) to select and update a record
2. Use [Object Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_object_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) in Journey Builder
3. Use [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/) together with SSJS, to perform an update of multiple records from Automation Studio.